# conditional output based on checkbox

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to populate many tables, but only show the ones the user requests.  For example, in the minimal example below, I split mtcars into three tables and I have three checkboxes.  I would like to display each table only if the appropriate check box is checked.

I tried using [condiditionalPanel](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.3/conditionalPanel.html), but that is not working.  The app does not respond to my inputs.  Maybe conditionalPanel only works for GUI inputs.

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    checkboxInput("cyl4", "Show 4 cylinders", value=FALSE),
    textOutput("box4"),
    checkboxInput("cyl6", "Show 6 cylinders", value=FALSE),
    textOutput("box6"),
    checkboxInput("cyl8", "Show 8 cylinders", value=FALSE),
    textOutput("box8"),

    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.cyl4 == TRUE",
      tableOutput("data4")
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.cyl6 == TRUE",
      tableOutput("data6")
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.cyl8 == TRUE",
      tableOutput("data8")
    )

  )

  server <- function(input, output) {

    output$box4 <- renderText(input$cyl4)
    output$box6 <- renderText(input$cyl6)
    output$box8 <- renderText(input$cyl8)

    output$data4 <- renderTable({mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 4, ]}, rownames = TRUE)
    output$data6 <- renderTable({mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 6, ]}, rownames = TRUE)
    output$data8 <- renderTable({mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 8, ]}, rownames = TRUE)
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Currently the shiny app shows all three tables and doesn't respond to the check boxes.  If only the cyl4 box is checked, I would like the app to show only table 'data4'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional argument has to be written in JavaScript where `TRUE` is spelled `true`. The below code should work.

```
library("shiny")

shinyApp(

    ui = fluidPage(
        checkboxInput("cyl4", "Show 4 cylinders", value=FALSE),
        textOutput("box4"),
        checkboxInput("cyl6", "Show 6 cylinders", value=FALSE),
        textOutput("box6"),
        checkboxInput("cyl8", "Show 8 cylinders", value=FALSE),
        textOutput("box8"),

        conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.cyl4 == true",
            tableOutput("data4")
        ),
        conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.cyl6 == true",
            tableOutput("data6")
        ),
        conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.cyl8 == true",
            tableOutput("data8")
        )

    ),

    server =function(input, output) {

        output$box4 <- renderText(input$cyl4)
        output$box6 <- renderText(input$cyl6)
        output$box8 <- renderText(input$cyl8)

        output$data4 <- renderTable({mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 4, ]}, rownames = TRUE)
        output$data6 <- renderTable({mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 6, ]}, rownames = TRUE)
        output$data8 <- renderTable({mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 8, ]}, rownames = TRUE)
    }

)
```

Comment: Just to note that "true" above can also be substituted with "1". E.g. condition "input.cyl8 == true" can also read "input.cyl8 == 1".

Comment: Thank you both Hellwalker and olorcain.  In coding you can be so close and yet so far away.  I decided to go with the 1 instead of true to save my future self headache.